# Symfony 4 allow_extra_fields is set to true but still getting - This form should not contain extra fields

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In my form builder configuration, I have set the value of allow_extra_fields to true, but still getting "This form should not contain extra fields" when I validate the form. Any idea what can be the reason?

Comment: Hi, please show the form type code. :)

Comment: @COil it's a dynamically generated class, so most of the fields are created on the fly, it works perfectly fine with 99% of records, but having an issue with some random records when I update the data.